# pegtl - how to skip spaces for the entire grammar

Tags: c++, parsing

I am trying to parse a very simple language with PEGTL. I think I have found the problem, but don't understand why; white spaces are not ignored. I understand it must be possible to not ignore white space so that indentation-aware languages can also be parsed. But I couldn't find a mechanism to "eat" white spaces by default. Given:

```
struct kw_enum : tao::pegtl::string<'e', 'n', 'u', 'm'> { };
struct enum_decl : tao::pegtl::seq<kw_enum, tao::pegtl::identifier, tao::pegtl::one<';'>> { };
```

the following cannot be parsed:

```
enum thing;
```

If I add `pegtl::space` between each token explicitly, then it works. But it would be major burden to do it in the entire grammar.

How can white spaces be ignored/eaten/skipped, like in C, without specifying those explicitly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a shortcut, you have to specify the grammar in a way that makes it unambiguous where and how many whitespaces you allow.

The best way to do it I think is to add a convenience rule template that allows matching a list (`tao::pegtl::seq`) of rules separated by any allowed separater (generally whitespace *plus* comments).

```
struct comment : tao::pegtl::disable< /* whatever your comment syntax is */ > {};
struct separator : tao::pegtl::sor< tao::pegtl::ascii::space, comment > {}; // either/or
struct seps : tao::pegtl::star< separator > {}; // Any separators, whitespace or comments

// Template to generate rule
// tao::pegtl::seq<Rule0, Separator, Rule1, Separator, Rule2, ... , Separator, RuleN>
template <typename Separator, typename... Rules>
struct interleaved;

template <typename Separator, typename Rule0, typename... RulesRest>
struct interleaved<Separator, Rule0, RulesRest...>
  : tao::pegtl::seq<Rule0, Separator, interleaved<Separator, RulesRest...>> {};

template <typename Separator, typename Rule0>
struct interleaved<Separator, Rule0>
  : Rule0 {};

// Note: interleaved<Separator /*, no Rule! */> intentionally not defined.

struct enum_decl : interleaved<seps, kw_enum, tao::pegtl::identifier, tao::pegtl::one<';'> {};
// Expands to:
seq<kw_enum, seps, interleaved<seps, identifier, one<';'>>> ==
seq<kw_enum, seps, seq<identifier, seps, interleaved<seps, one<';'>>>> ==
seq<kw_enum, seps, seq<identifier, seps, one<';'>> ==
seq<kw_enum, seps, identifier, seps, one<';'>>
```

Basically, doing something like the above, you only need to replace `tao::pegtl::seq<R...>` with `interleaved<seps, R...>`, but you could even make a separate alias for that:

```
template<typename... Rules>
using sseq = interleaved<seps, Rules...>;

// Now you only have to replace tao::pegtl::seq with sseq
struct enum_decl : sseq<kw_enum, tao::pegtl::identifier, tao::pegtl::one<';'>> {};
```

This strategy is mostly needed not because of whitespace-significant languages but because you don't have an earlier tokenizer step in the parsing that would separate the `enum` from the `thing`. Another strategy would be to implement that first, and do the later-stage parsing based on a stream of tokens instead of a stream of characters, but that is a larger rewrite and has its own drawbacks.

> Note: I haven't compiled the code, but the point here should be the strategy. Please leave a comment if there is a compile error (I hope I haven't messed up the variadic templates) or if something is unclear.
>
> Note 2: Also you probably don't want to replace *every* `seq` with `sseq`. For example, if you have the logical and (`&&`) defined as `seq<one<'&'>, one<'&'>>`, that's something you probably don't want to change.

Comment: I _thought_ about an approach, though couldn't express it correctly or my idea wouldn't work to begin with; make a class template that surrounds given rule (as template argument) with `star<space>`. I'll try your idea, and see how it works. Thanks!

Comment: That's [pegtl::pad<Rule, SepL, SepR>](https://github.com/taocpp/PEGTL/blob/master/doc/Rule-Reference.md#pad-r-s-t--s-) but you probably don't want that because you have to replace each element of every `seq` instead of just the `seq`s.

Comment: Please see https://github.com/taocpp/PEGTL/discussions/274 for a better way to write `interleaved`.

Answer (score -1):

```
char *removeSpaces(char *str) 
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (str[i])
    {
        if (str[i] != ' ')
           str[j++] = str[i];
        i++;
    }
    str[j] = '\0';
    return str; 
}
```

Comment: would be nice to write some commentary in your answer to explain your code

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27780780)

Comment: @Thangavel Do you know what pegtl is?